# How to modify the layout for the Default Display form inside a List

Tags: list, development, page-layout, form, view

I am working on an Issue Tracking list inside SharePoint 2013. but when a user clicks on an item , the description field will occupy only a small area of the page , while most of the page will be blank as follow:-

[image]

so using F12 Developer Tools on IE i detect the marckup for the Description field as follow:-
[image]

where it is mentioned that it have a `Width=350`, so i add a Script Editor web part to the displayform and i specify the following to expand the field from 350 to 1000:-

```
<style>
#SPFieldNote
{width: 1000;

}
<style>
```

but the result is that the display form will display nothing when clicking on an item as follow:-

[image]

Of course if i remove the ScriptEditor web part the form will be shown again..

so can anyone advice from where i can force the default display item view to occupy the whole page size ?
Thanks